# Prove that $E=\{(x,0): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is complete

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, filters, complete-spaces

Let $\mathscr{B}=\{(-a,a)\times \mathbb{R}:a>0\}$. It's easy to see that $\mathscr{B}$ is the filter of neighborhoods of the origin in a topology compatible with the linear structure of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, namely, $\mathscr{F}(0,0)=\{U \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}: U \supset (-a,a) \times \mathbb{R} \ (\exists a>0) \}$.

> **My question:** How to prove that $E=\{(x,0): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is complete?

By definition, a subset $E$ of a topological vector space is said to be complete if every Cauchy filter on $E$ converges to a point $x$ of $E$.

I started considering a Cauchy sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ in $E$. So that, $y_n=0$ por all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ is linear and continous, we obtain that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Now it's easy to see that $(x_n,0) \rightarrow (x,0)$ in the topology above mentioned.

Considering now a Cauchy filter $\mathscr{F}$ in $E$, the uniform continuity of $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ ensures that $\pi_1(\mathscr{F})$ is a Cauchy filter in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\pi_1(\mathscr{F}) \rightarrow x$. How could I prove that $\mathscr{F} \rightarrow (x,0)$ in $E$ in the subspace topology?

Comment: Wouldn't $x_n$ have its elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ rather than in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I had made a typo, the correct is $\{(x,0):x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Isn't $E$ isomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: As @JustinYoung suggests, one observation is that $E$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, so your problem might be reduced to knowing or proving that $\mathbb R$ is complete. In any case the proof of that standard result will inform your solution here.

Comment: And in the case that I don't have isomorphism, for example if $E=\mathbb{R}^{2}$. How would I prove that this space is complete? Trying to use the definition above.

Comment: You could try starting with $\mathbb R$. Are you trying to prove that $\mathbb R$ is complete from first principles? What are you allowed to assume?

Comment: I can assume that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. The idea is to show how to use the definition above to show that a space is complete.

Comment: Sounds like you want to show that a product of complete spaces is complete?

Comment: @JustinYoung:  I think the idea is that the containing TVS is *not* a complete space, as the local basis $\mathscr{B}$ does not give even us a Hausdorff space.  However the subspace topology induced on the $x$-axis is the usual complete metric.  The exercise involves using the notion of Cauchy filter rather than Cauchy sequence to accommodate the non-metric nature of the containing topology.

Comment: @hardmath A-ha, reading the question, what a novel idea! I actually wasn't familiar with Cauchy filters and it seemed like an artificial idea, so it's good there's a reason for it.